# matrix contains a decimal type values?

Tags: java

hello I have the following matrix:
how do I check that contains decimal data type?

```
 int row =10;
 int column = 10;
 Object[][] m= new Object[rows][column]
```

Comment: by using instanceof for a specific index value

Comment: Why don't you use a  `int[]` or `double[]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you create an Object array you can store any types of objects in there. You can check for any given given value if it is numeric and capable of representing decimals:

```
public static boolean isDecimalValue(Object value) {
    return value != null && 
        (value instanceof Double || 
         value instanceof Float ||
         value instanceof BigDecimal
        );
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(isDecimalValue(42)); // false
System.out.println(isDecimalValue(6.666d)); // true
System.out.println(isDecimalValue("potato")); // false
System.out.println(isDecimalValue(null)); // false
System.out.println(isDecimalValue(new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793"))); // true
```

Comment: if I wanted to assess if it contains numbers or characters?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean exactly with 'characters'. Look at regular expressions. Or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof operator. [This link](http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator) may help you.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work                                if(data[i][5] instanceof(Double))

Comment: it should be like : if(data[i][5] instanceof Double )

Answer (score 0):

if (obj instanceof Double){
//logic}